# Positioning of android list items

Tags: android, listview

I want to have ListView with some customized (layout) items. Background for those item has transparency on its bottom side. I want next item (after this customized) to be positioned a little bit top (something like minus margin in CSS). If in LinearLayout of list item (this special list item) I can do android:layout_marginTop with minus values? It seems to doesn't work, so what is the better solution? I need to little positioning next list item.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that the listView exposes this functionality.   As an image trick, however, if you can modify the images, just put the transparent section (I assume it's a shadow?) on the top of your listItem background image so that it **LOOKS** like the item above casts a shadow, but in reality the shadow is part of the background of your listItem